# How can Fantomex be an anomaly?

Tags: comics, marvel

In Uncanny X-Force #20, a member of the Captain Britain Corps claims that [Fantomex is an anomaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUy3I.png) and does not exist in any other dimension.  Yet, alternate reality version of Fantomex have been shown numerous times.

- Days of Future Now (Earth-5700): Fantomex became the host of Sublime.
- Here Comes Tomorrow (Earth-15104): Fantomex has become one of Sublime's U-Men and is known as Apollyon the Destroyer.
- Even in an earlier issue of Uncanny X-Force we see Fantomex fighting a Deathlok version of himself.

Is there an in-universe explanation for this or is it simply a retcon?

Comment: `does not exist in any other dimension` - that THEY know of.

Answer (score 3):

Considering Uncanny X-Force #20 is the most recent of those comics and the Captain Britain Corps is a multi-dimensional organisation I would trust them and say that they are right to consider Fantomex to be an anomaly (And accept the writers ret-con).

Though, on the other hand, from my cursory search I cannot find  a single Captain Britain from any of the universes you mention. If their primary sources for 'Who's Who across the multiverse' is personal experience *and there is no <strike>one</strike> Captain Britain from Earth-5700 or Earth 15105*, how would they know? It may simply be rhetoric to disparage Fantomex.

Without more details it's impossible to decide, but this is the best answer I think we can manage with what we have, I.e this is a retcon.